# Get from the same table the value of one column from different ID

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have a mapping table with ID and D_DESC column. I want to take a D_DESC value passing more than one ID for example:

```
ID  D_DESC
1   DESC_ID1
2   DESC_ID2
3   DESC_ID3
```

The result should be

```
D_DESC1    D_DESC2
DESC_ID1   DESC_ID2
```

I did this query:

```
SELECT t1.D_DESC AS DESC_1,t2.D_DESC AS DESC_2 
FROM  Tabel t1,Tabel t2 
WHERE '1'=t1.ID  
AND   '2'=t2.ID
```

That return exactly what I want, but if I want to put also a null value if the id isn't pass. For example i want also to show this result from the query (
`SELECT t1.D_DESC AS DESC_1,t2.D_DESC AS DESC_2 FROM  Tabel t1,Tabel t2 WHERE '1'=t1.ID  AND  ''=t2.ID;`):

```
D_DESC1    D_DESC2
DESC_ID1   null
```

Suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If, you want to just one row with different `IDS`, then you can do that :

```
select max(case when id = 1 then D_DESC end) DESC_1,
       max(case when id = 2 then D_DESC end) DESC_2
from table t;
```

Comment: Perfect,is what i was looking.

Answer (score 0):

This is a `PIVOT` operation.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
PIVOT(MAX(D_DESC) FOR id IN (
             1 AS D_DESC1
            ,2 AS D_DESC2
            ,3 AS D_DESC3
            ));
```

This gives :

```
|  D_DESC1 |  D_DESC2 |  D_DESC3 |
|----------|----------|----------|
| DESC_ID1 | DESC_ID2 | DESC_ID3 |
```

In case  you want to pass `NULL` for `id2`, write

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
PIVOT(MAX(D_DESC) FOR id IN (
            1 AS  D_DESC1
        ,NULL AS  D_DESC2
           ,3 AS  D_DESC3
            ));
```

which gives

```
|  D_DESC1 | D_DESC2 |  D_DESC3 |
|----------|---------|----------|
| DESC_ID1 |  (null) | DESC_ID3 |
```